# Unable to expand the child of a stack with respect to the width

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want the text to occupy the width of the cached network image but it is not expanding to the whole width of the image.

**My code:-**

```
Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      CachedNetworkImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        imageUrl: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR9f_RbuB35f9pjcb2FigHaYKa0FwQYFW6DnQ&usqp=CAU',
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      ),
                      Wrap(
                        direction: Axis.vertical,
                        children: [
                          RotatedBox(
                            quarterTurns: 3,
                            child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5,bottom: 5),
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              color: Colors.blue[200],
                              child: FittedBox(
                                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                                child: Text(
                                  'D A Y - ${index+1}',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.gugi(
                                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                        color: Colors.grey[300]
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
```

current result:-

[image]

expected result:-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `Positioned` as a child of `Stack` with properties `top:0, bottom:0, left:0`. This will force its child to expand just like you need. **UPD:** Then use `Transform.rotate` widget on `Text` to rotate it.

[image]

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Material App Bar'),
          ),
          body: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Image(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR9f_RbuB35f9pjcb2FigHaYKa0FwQYFW6DnQ&usqp=CAU'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  width: double.infinity,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 0,
                  top: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 100, // Set width to your likings
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Transform.rotate(
                        angle: -3.14 /
                            2, // use pi from math package for more precise
                        child: Text('Brown Fox'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use an Align + RotatedBox to put you widget on the left side of the screen, instead of the Wrap.

You might need to use another widget to expand your RotatedBox.

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-layout-cheat-sheet-5363348d037e